# Chrome & Firebase Push Notifications service worker not ready

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase, push-notification, service-worker

In following this Code Lab:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/

I downloaded the `push-notifications.git` project and uploaded the final `/completed/08-unsubscribe` example to my HTTPS web server.

When I visit this page for the first time, the console log reads:

```
Service Worker is supported
sw.js:24 Started
sw.js:28 Installed
sw.js:32 Activated
```

Visiting the page a second time reads:

```
Service Worker is supported
```

The issue I'm trying to debug is that I'm not getting a `Service Worker is ready` output from this function:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  console.log('Service Worker is supported');
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function() {
    return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
  }).then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {
    reg = serviceWorkerRegistration;
    subscribeButton.disabled = false;
    console.log('Service Worker is ready :^)', reg);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Service Worker Error :^(', error);
  });
}
```

Where is the hangup in preventing my Subscribe button from becoming enabled and firing either the `console.log('Service Worker is ready :^)', reg);` or `console.log('Service Worker Error :^(', error);` messages?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.
If you give console, it should print. I verified it, It works.
Just check by giving just the console in then.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  console.log('Service Worker is supported');
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function() {
  return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
}).then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {

   console.log('Service Worker is ready :^)', reg);
}).catch(function(error) {
   console.log('Service Worker Error :^(', error);
});
}
```

Comment: Hmm, here's what I'm seeing on my end -- the subscribe button never becomes enabled and I don't get a ready or error event: http://i.imgur.com/X1dhsQM.png

Comment: just give the console log before button enabling. And can you tell how did you intialise subscribeButton